# How to disable Restrictions mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a requirement, that I have to disable **Restrictions mode** in iPhone setting through coding.

I have to disable *camera* and *wifi/Mobile data* once I enter a specific restricted area.
After a long research, I got I have to disable the Restriction mode in device setting.

So how can I do that through coding ?

For reference :

[image]

Comment: You can't.  An app doesn't have that level of access to device settings

Comment: @Paulw11 : We can access device setting through coding. We can open device setting but how to handle that restriction mode and if not then any other way to disable camera and wifi ?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it would be to use an MDM that pushes a profile to restrict the device and pushes a new profile when the app detects that the device has entered/exited the specific area; even then you cannot disable WiFi and mobile data

Comment: Ok thanks for your valuable suggestion :) Thanks alot

Comment: One side note, in iOS10 it is not possible anymore to use a 'deep link' into the settings. So also setting Settings from the App might be limited in future versions.

Comment: @SRNayak, I don't know what are you going to do. But you can do it with MDM solution. once the user enter the area, send a msg to the MDM server, and the server send a new restricted profile to the device.

Comment: @Horst : Ok , what u understood that is my requirement. :) once I'll enter some area that time I need to disable camera and wifi

Comment: @SRNayak then make use of MDM

Comment: @Horst : Ok thanks for ur suggestion. Can u tell me, app will not be rejected by Apple  to use of MDM ?

Comment: well, MDM is not related to the app. using mdm, user device would enroll devices in your enterprise environment. After enrollment, the mdm server can push profiles to the device to restrict them

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Because that is not allowed. Apple does not allow apps to update or access settings app. You can ask for permissions which are listed by apple like photo library, camera, location etc. But there is not way to access/update Restrictions mode programatically. You can prompt user for that and user can manually do it.

There is no work around for this. Sorry for that.